# print the nth digit of a number in JAVA

Tags: java

I want to print nth digit of a number (from left to right) in JAVA. Here's what I've tried, I'm a total noob.

public class NewClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {

```
    System.out.println("enter number: ");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    int number = s.nextInt();

    System.out.println("enter n: ");
    Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num = n.nextInt();


    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {

        number = number / 10;
    };
   System.out.println("The nth Digit = " + number);
}
```

Comment: Your title and prose do not match the code. Your code just finds a number, but shows no attempt at printing the nth digit. Please show your attempt to solve the problem. "I am a noob" is neither relevant nor an attempt.

Comment: My first time here in stack, mistakenly pasted the wrong code. Now can't edit. Here's what I've tried, can you please check? https://www.codepile.net/pile/Lq1GXNBn

Comment: You can [edit]. Don't post links to code

Comment: Your division logic does not make sense if you are trying to find the nth number reading from left to right because division by 10 takes off the numbers from right to left instead.

Comment: Exactly, from my 2 days learning java this is all i can do. I've no idea how to get it from left to right, so tried the other way around. Maybe there's a small fix?

Answer (score 0):

Following @ryan 's explanation, I found a solve in my way.

```
package com.mycompany.lab;
import java.util.Scanner;

int reversed = 0, digit;

System.out.println("enter number: ");
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
int number=s.nextInt();

while(number != 0) {
    
  // get last digit from num
  digit = number % 10;
  reversed = reversed * 10 + digit;

  // remove the last digit from num
  number /= 10;
}

System.out.println("enter n: ");
Scanner n=new Scanner(System.in);

int num=n.nextInt();

for(int i=1;i<num;i++){

reversed = reversed / 10;
};

while(reversed > 10){
    reversed = reversed % 10;
}
    
System.out.println("The nth Digit = " + reversed);
}  
}
```